# Replace dictionary values containing array of integers with array of objects

Tags: django, python-3.x, object

I am currently working with django and I am able to fetch the JSON of my model.But one of the keys of the JSON contains an array of numbers which I need to replace with array of objects of those numbers.Below is the query to get json of the `Contexts` model

```
queryset = serializers.serialize("json", Contexts.objects.all())
```

This is what I get

```
[{"model": "app.contexts", "pk": 1, "fields": {"context_name": "tech-experts", "context_description": "this is for tech experts", "context_priority": "H", "users": [1, 3, 4]}}, {"model": "app.contexts", "pk": 2, "fields": {"context_name": "video-conf-issue", "context_description": "bla bla", "context_priority": "H", "users": [4, 5]}}, {"model": "app.contexts", "pk": 3, "fields": {"context_name": "video-conf-issue", "context_description": "bla bla", "context_priority": "L", "users": [3]}}, {"model": "app.contexts", "pk": 15, "fields": {"context_name": "Network debug", "context_description": "Group for debugging network issues", "context_priority": "L", "users": [2]}}]
```

Now I am interested in just the `fields` values.So I do this

```
result = [i.get('fields') for i in ast.literal_eval(queryset)]
```

So now I get this

```
[{'context_priority': 'H', 'context_name': 'tech-experts', 'context_description': 'this is for tech experts', 'users': [1, 3, 4]}, {'context_priority': 'H', 'context_name': 'video-conf-issue', 'context_description': 'bla bla', 'users': [4, 5]}, {'context_priority': 'L', 'context_name': 'video-conf-issue', 'context_description': 'bla bla', 'users': [3]}, {'context_priority': 'L', 'context_name': 'Network debug', 'context_description': 'Group for debugging network issues', 'users': [2]}]
```

Now as you can see `users` has an array which contains integers.Basically these integers are user ids and I want the user objects of these ids.

So my `User` model object for the `userId` 1, it will be

```
User.objects.filter(userId=1)
```

So in order to achieve this I do the below operation

```
[i.update({"users":[].append(User.objects.filter(userId=j))}) for i in result for j in i.get("users")]
```

But now I get the resulting value for the key `users` as None

```
[{'context_description': 'this is for tech experts', 'users': None, 'context_priority': 'H', 'context_name': 'tech-experts'}, {'context_description': 'bla bla', 'users': None, 'context_priority': 'H', 'context_name': 'video-conf-issue'}, {'context_description': 'bla bla', 'users': None, 'context_priority': 'L', 'context_name': 'video-conf-issue'}, {'context_description': 'Group for debugging network issues', 'users': None, 'context_priority': 'L', 'context_name': 'Network debug'}]
```

How can I achieve this?

***Added the `Contexts` and `User` model below***

```
class User(models.Model):
    userId = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = False)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=getUserImagePath,null=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(null = True)


class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    context_priority = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='context_users')
```

Comment: it will be `User.objects.filter(id=j)`

Comment: dont we usually do User.object.filter(pk=j) ? try changing to [i.update({"users":[].append(User.objects.filter(pk=j))}) for i in result for j in i.get("users")]

Comment: Firstly, show your models. Secondly, for complex serialization you really should be using django-rest-framework, which allows you to customize your Serializer class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated the question with the models.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
[i.update({"users":[].append(User.objects.filter(userId=j))}) for i in result for j in i.get("users")]
```

to

```
[i.update({"users":[].append(User.objects.filter(pk=j))}) for i in result for j in i.get("users")]
```

Comment: I need to check against the field `userId` since thats one of the fields in `User` model

Comment: The `.append(..)` will result in `None`, not in a list with one element. You can use `[User.objects.filter(userId=j)]` for that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hey your solution got me close but it only turns the last element of each array as object and discards the rest. Something like `[{'context_description': 'this is for tech experts', 'users': [<QuerySet [<User: User object (4)>]>], 'context_name': 'tech-experts', 'context_priority': 'H'}, {'context_description': 'bla bla', 'users': [<QuerySet [<User: User object (5)>]>], 'context_name': 'video-conf-issue', 'context_priority': 'H'}, {'context_description': 'bla bla', 'users': [<QuerySet [<User: User object (3)>]>], 'context_name': 'video-conf-issue', 'context_priority': 'L'} ...`

Comment: @SouvikRay: that's not my solution :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok :D but can you please tell why do I get only last element of each array as an object and the rest is discarded?Any changes in the query?

Comment: @SouvikRay: because dictionary comprehension works that way, if a key occurs multiple times, only the last one is retrieved, since the fact that this is a list, is merely a coincidence according to Python.